# Why responses my heroku hosted container app with "Not authoritative"

Tags: docker, kotlin, heroku, graalvm, http4k

I try to run [my simple Web-App](https://github.com/Tait1337/example-html5-landingpage-buddah) as Docker Container within [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).
When build and run the container locally all works fine.

But on accessing the generated endpoint https://html5-landingpage-buddah.herokuapp.com/ Heroku responses with HTTP 400 Bad Request and the message "Not authoritative"

Logs inside Heroku don't help much:

```
2020-09-19T14:45:45.269487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=html5-landingpage-buddah.herokuapp.com request_id=5f07ea7e-d925-4fbe-b7ba-29387a3284cc fwd="XX.XX.XX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=212 protocol=https
```

I did a research for the error but found no helpful information.
Also re-creating the App in Heroku, renaming the URL and moving the App to another Region did not help.

---

Here is the log from restart to the first request on the web app:

```
2021-06-15T17:11:36.977277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./app`
2021-06-15T17:11:39.852345+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO de.clique.westwood.example.html5.landingpage.buddah.App - Server started on port 54225
2021-06-15T17:11:39.852374+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO de.clique.westwood.example.html5.landingpage.buddah.App - Serving albums from ./static/album
2021-06-15T17:11:41.363857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-15T17:11:48.162254+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=html5-landingpage-buddah.herokuapp.com request_id=85c642cb-a48d-41ac-89e1-7a520749e9bc fwd="94.31.82.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=421 bytes=219 protocol=https
2021-06-15T17:11:48.275223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=html5-landingpage-buddah.herokuapp.com request_id=406e9e77-f40e-47b9-a33b-af0af5b8f171 fwd="94.31.82.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=421 bytes=219 protocol=https
2021-06-15T17:11:48.520876+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=html5-landingpage-buddah.herokuapp.com request_id=d3782734-765c-45f1-98a8-04e2098e7267 fwd="94.31.82.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=421 bytes=219 protocol=https
2021-06-15T17:11:48.906097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=html5-landingpage-buddah.herokuapp.com request_id=79e4404f-e505-4c16-9778-9f72882d74be fwd="94.31.82.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=421 bytes=219 protocol=https
```

Comment: Provide log. From the moment you first start the app to the moment you open the website. The log you provided is not relevant to your app. It's the `router` and not your application. Furthermore provide build.log.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Not Authoritative` simply means that Heroku is unable to redirect the traffic from the said domain name to your application.

According to [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime),

> The web process must listen for HTTP traffic on `$PORT`, which is set by Heroku. `EXPOSE` in `Dockerfile` is not respected, but can be used for local testing. Only HTTP requests are supported.

You will need to replace your `EXPOSE` and `ENTRYPOINT` as such

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java -jar ./app --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT" ]
```

Comment: With your solution the same problem stays.
Please note that I compile my java programm to a native executable (see dockerfile in the linked git repository). Therfore I changed your command to:
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "./app --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT" ]
This is the same as in the current version this works well on my machine. But deployed on Heroku occurs the same error appears.

Comment: Here the logs
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh -c ./app\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\17829`
app[web.1]: [main] INFO de.clique.westwood.example.html5.landingpage.buddah.App - Server started on port 17829
app[web.1]: [main] INFO de.clique.westwood.example.html5.landingpage.buddah.App - Serving albums from ./static/album
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=html5-landingpage-buddah.herokuapp.com request_id=5b509c13-9ea9-45d3-8d95-129c2470f2b6 fwd="4.3.2.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=421 bytes=219 protocol=https